# OpenSSH Server - anonymous account

Tags: ssh, openssh

so I wanted to make a simple shell app for fun, via SSH. I made a custom shell using Python and the `cmd` module (that was pretty easy to make), added the shell in `/etc/shells`, made an account on my server (which login name is `visitor`), made the custom shell its default shell, and put a simple password (`visitor`), and it works pretty well.

But here's the deal: I want to remove the password step. I would like that when someone types in `ssh visitor@myserver.org`, it goes straight through to the shell (autologin), without any previous step from the user, and I want this to only apply on the `visitor` account (not on any other existing account, even if a way to add more accounts like this would be cool (every account in a group?)).

Thanks in advance for any solution or answer! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was answering similar question on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280168/ssh-virtual-kiosk-does-permitemptypasswords-yes-work-how-to-make-ssh-use). In short, I don't think there is possibility to do that without patching OpenSSH. But you can make `sshd` accept empty passwords:

```
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

Also you need to modify PAM to accept empty passwords by changing `nullok_secure`  to `nullok` in  `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

There is also `none` authentication, which `sshtron` is based on, but it is [supposed to fail by the RFC4252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-5.2).

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (none).
```

To achieve the same behaviour, you would need to patch openssh server, or create a server using something different.

Comment: `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` has exactly the effect I wanted with the OpenSSH client I have on my PC. Thanks a lot ! :D